# Dual monitor not working when 'nomodeset' is used

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, nomodeset

I am using an HP Pavillion g6 laptop running 12.04, and the laptop screen is simply black if I don't apply 'nomodeset' on startup. However, including this has lead to the laptop not recognising an external monitor.

I have searched around online and this seems to be a problem that a number of people with this laptop have experienced, but so far I haven't seen a solution, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

nomodeset disables kernel mode setting (KMS), which is needed by the graphics drivers you are using; there is no workaround.  Some proprietary drivers don't require KMS; try installing those.

Comment: What do you mean by "proprietary drivers"?